# DataGridView change cell background color based on the row selected from another table

Tags: c#, datagridview

I want to make a lotto statistics app where in one table I have the results and in another table I have the numbers and when I select a row from the first table I want the numbers to be highlighted on the second one.

I tryed to do it as a test based on some value that changes when I click a button. It makes the first change but that's all.

I tryed every method I could find but nothing is working.[I put an image with a simillar thind done with php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmhB2.png)

[image]

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private object valoare = 2;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        int numar = 1;
        dataGridView1.CurrentCell = null;
        dataGridView1.RowHeadersVisible = false;
        dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersVisible = false;
        dataGridView1.AllowUserToResizeColumns = false;
        dataGridView1.AllowUserToResizeRows = false;
        dataGridView1.Enabled = false;
        dataGridView1.RowCount = 7;
        dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 7;
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value = numar;
                numar++;
            }
        }
        dataGridView1.CellFormatting += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellFormattingEventHandler(this.dataGridView1_CellFormatting);
    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(Object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Style.BackColor = Color.White;
        if ((int)e.Value % (int)valoare == 0)
        {
          dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int contor = 1;
        if (contor % 2 == 1)
        {
            valoare = 7;
        }
        else
        {
            valoare = 5;
        }
        contor++;
        //valoare = 7;
        dataGridView1.CellFormatting += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellFormattingEventHandler(this.dataGridView1_CellFormatting);
    }
}
```

Comment: The code you have posted does show any attempt at doing what you describe. And, it appears you are unsure what grid event to use. So, it may help to break the problem down into pieces. One piece would be the grid on the left. The left grid is the grid we want to be looking at in order to set the cell “highlights” in the grid on the right. In other words, WHEN the user selects a “different” row in the grid on the left, you want the grid on the right to reflect the numbers from the newly selected row in the left grid.

Comment: Your current code addresses the grid on the right; however, it does not show anything related to “setting” the values from the grid on the left. I would suggest, that after you get the grid on the left set up, that, you wire up two (2) events in the left grid….  The grids `RowLeave` event and the grids `RowEnter` event. When the grid’s `RowLeave` event fires, the user has clicked on another row in the grid. So, this would be a good place to call your current code to set the grid on the right to a clean base format. Thus, removing any previously “highlighted” values.

Comment: After the `RowLeave` event fires, then the grid’s `RowEnter` event fires, it is in this event that you want to get the cell values from the “selected” row in the grid on the left. Once you have all six values, then you can create a method to “highlight” those values in the grid on the right. This is a very general description of how to proceed. There are some caveats that you need to address, however, they are trivial. This will hopefully get you going.

Comment: One important thing to keep in mind is what “event” you place certain code. In the current posted code, you basically have a runaway UI. The grids `CellFormatting` fires OFTEN, like when the user brings the cursor over the grid among many other things. If you run the code, I am confident you will see a “sluggishness” if you try to move the form window around. It will move, but it will skip and drag.

Comment: This is because the `CellFormatting` is doing A LOT of unnecessary work… namely executing your code needlessly over and over. Point being, you don’t need to set each cell’s back color, unless the user selects a different row from the grid on the left. I hope that makes sense. Therefore, I can easily see a method that does what the current code does, however, it is ONLY called when the user “leaves” the selected row in the grid on the left. Please try this and if you have issues, I can post a full example.

Comment: Lastly, you may find the following links useful in asking questions on SO… The [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) section shows how SO works. The [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may help. In addition, you may find the SO [Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) section useful.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I manage to solve it!